# How to create automatic loop for this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, loops

I have created a code for disabling/enabling button in a page:

```
btna = [
{
  "id":"#btn123",
  "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4849-p4850-o1",
  'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
  'closeTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
},
{
  "id":"#btn1234",
  "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4940-p4850-o2",
  'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
  'closeTime' : "June 25, 2019 14:00:00",
},
{
  "id":"#btn12345",
  "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4941-p4850-o3",
  'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
  'closeTime' : "June 28, 2019 14:00:00",
}
]
$(document).ready(function(){
  let openTime
  let closeTime
  let button
  let itemForm
  let now = Date.now();
  btna.map(function(item){
    openTime = (new Date(item.openTime)).getTime()
    closeTime = (new Date(item.closeTime)).getTime()
    button = $( item.id )
    itemForm = $( item.formId )
    if (closeTime > now && openTime < now ) {
      // Button in correct time period
      button.addClass("active")
      // if you don't want to auto hide form in page startup just comment out this line 
      itemForm.hide()
      button.click(function(){
        $( item.formId ).toggle(250)
      })
    }else{
      // Button is'nt in its time period
      button.addClass("ex1")
      itemForm.hide()
    }
  })
})
```

My problem is the array section, where I have to add several dates. I'm wondering if there is a way to set an openTime and a closeTime and then, it automatically adds 7 days (1 week) to each of them.

This is what I tried:

```
let openTime= new Date("June 23, 2019 14:00:00");
let closeTime= new Date("June 26, 2019 14:00:00");
btna = [
    {
        "id":"#btn123",
        "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4849-p4850-o1",
        'openTime' : openTime,
        'closeTime' : closeTime,
    },
    {
        "id":"#btn1234",
        "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4940-p4850-o2",
        'openTime' : openTime.setDate(openTime.getDate() + 7),
        'closeTime' : closeTime.setDate(openTime.getDate() + 7),
    },
    {
        "id":"#btn12345",
        "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4941-p4850-o3",
        'openTime' : openTime.setDate(openTime.getDate() + 7),
        'closeTime' : closTime.setDate(openTime.getDate() + 7),
    }
]

$(document).ready(function(){
    let button
    let itemForm
    let now = Date.now();
    btna.map(function(item){
        openTime = (new Date(item.openTime)).getTime()
        closeTime = (new Date(item.closeTime)).getTime()
        button = $( item.id )
        itemForm = $( item.formId )
        if (openTime < now && closeTime > now) {
            // Button in correct time period
            button.addClass("active")
            // if you don't want to auto hide form in page startup just comment out this line 
            itemForm.hide()
            button.click(function(){
                 $( item.formId ).toggle(250)
            })
        }else{
            // Button is'nt in its time period
            button.addClass("hide")
            itemForm.hide()
        }
    })
})
```

However, this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm sue there is another shorter way to insert openTime and closeTime inside a loop, something like this:
    let openTime += 7
    let closeTime += 7
But, I don't know how to map this variables inside btna array!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What's your expected output? Also, `btna.map()` will return a new array, if you are not going to use this new array, you should use `btna.forEach()` instead.

Comment: As I've mentioned, instead of defining various dates individually, I want to define a starting point dates  ( openTime and closeTime) and assigne them to the first item in array, and for the rest, just add one week in each step.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use built in [Date functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to correctly handle date objects:

```js
const btna = [
{
  "id":"#btn123",
  "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4849-p4850-o1",
  'openTime' : "June 24, 2019 14:00:00",
  'closeTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
},
{
  "id":"#btn1234",
  "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4940-p4850-o2",
  'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
  'closeTime' : "June 25, 2019 14:00:00",
},
{
  "id":"#btn12345",
  "formId" : "#wpcf7-f4941-p4850-o3",
  'openTime' : "June 23, 2019 14:00:00",
  'closeTime' : "June 28, 2019 14:00:00",
}
];


const arr = btna.map(el => {
 el.openTime = addDays(7, el.openTime);
 el.closeTime = addDays(7, el.closeTime);
 
 return el;
});

function addDays(days, dateString) {
 let date = new Date(dateString);
 date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
 return date;
}

console.log(arr);
```